# Capturing visible text from Power shell window for the command that is not internal to power shell

Tags: powershell, command, command-prompt, powershell-3.0, out

Tried using '>' and 'OUT' commands but it is writing different output to the file that is not appearing in power shell window. Please note that these commands are application specific.

Comment: Please provide some example code, error message, etc.

Comment: what does `Please note that these commands are application specific` mean? exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any output to a variable like below 
$output = dir

Answer (score 0):

`>` will only redirect `stdout` (also called "success stream"). If you want to redirect all possible streams, use `*>`.

You can read more about redirection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried as you mentioned but still it is capturing output not appearing on power shell window. Using *> just increased the lines of output in this case.

Comment: @SudhakarKumar Please add your code, your current result and your expected result to your question as Alex_P already requested.